# Gedmo Loggable table ext_log_entries not found

Tags: symfony

I try to use Gedmo/Loggable on Symfony 4, but the table "ext_log_entries" from Gedmo doesn't exist.

Where can I find a migration or similar for this table?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Can't you create your own migration with `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` ? (for this command you need the https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)

Comment: My mistake ... :D